# Apache segfault errors for child processes

Tags: apache, segmentation-fault

Apache on production server is failing periodically. Apache logs show segfault errors for child processes.

Core dump backtrace shows next:

```
#0  0x00007fc2462d6617 in ?? ()
#1  0x00007fc24d9458b8 in _hooks ()
#2  0x00007fc2498c798f in ?? () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#3  0x00007fc2498ce342 in ?? () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#4  0x00007fc2498ce5c8 in zend_hash_graceful_reverse_destroy ()
   from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#5  0x00007fc2498c26b5 in ?? () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#6  0x00007fc24986d4cd in php_module_shutdown ()
   from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#7  0x00007fc24986d579 in php_module_shutdown_wrapper ()
   from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#8  0x00007fc24994de51 in ?? () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#9  0x00007fc24ce467d7 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libapr-1.so.0
#10 0x00007fc24ce45684 in apr_pool_destroy () from /usr/lib/libapr-1.so.0
#11 0x00007fc24d72b4ce in clean_child_exit (code=0)
    at /build/buildd/apache2-2.2.14/server/mpm/prefork/prefork.c:196
#12 0x00007fc24d72b8f9 in accept_mutex_on (child_num_arg=<value optimized out>)
    at /build/buildd/apache2-2.2.14/server/mpm/prefork/prefork.c:212
#13 child_main (child_num_arg=<value optimized out>)
    at /build/buildd/apache2-2.2.14/server/mpm/prefork/prefork.c:568
#14 0x00007fc24d72bb5a in make_child (s=0x7fc24f517938, slot=3)
    at /build/buildd/apache2-2.2.14/server/mpm/prefork/prefork.c:758
#15 0x00007fc24d72c7e4 in perform_idle_server_maintenance (
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
    _pconf=<value optimized out>, plog=<value optimized out>,
    s=<value optimized out>)
    at /build/buildd/apache2-2.2.14/server/mpm/prefork/prefork.c:893
#16 ap_mpm_run (_pconf=<value optimized out>, plog=<value optimized out>,
    s=<value optimized out>)
    at /build/buildd/apache2-2.2.14/server/mpm/prefork/prefork.c:1097
#17 0x00007fc24d701350 in main (argc=3, argv=0x7fff9a1da0d8)
    at /build/buildd/apache2-2.2.14/server/main.c:742
```

I have updated Apache from 2.2.14 to 2.2.20 and PHP from 5.3.2 to 5.3.6 but this error still exists.
What could be causing this problem?

UPDATE
Here php -v output:

```
root@host:~# php -v
PHP 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.1 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Aug 29 2011 23:39:16)
Copyright (c) 1997-2011 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2011 Zend Technologies
    with eAccelerator v1.0-dev, Copyright (c) 2004-2012 eAccelerator, by eAccelerator
```

php -m:

```
root@host:~# php -m
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dba
dom
eAccelerator
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
imagick
imap
intl
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
memcache
mhash
ming
mysql
mysqli
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
ps
pspell
readline
recode
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
snmp
soap
sockets
SPL
sqlite3
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tidy
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlrpc
xmlwriter
xsl
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
eAccelerator
```

Also I tried to disable eAccelerator but nothing was changed.

Comment: Is APC installed? Googling suggests that the APC module might be causing the crash with certain Apache configurations.

Comment: I have updated first message. No, APC is not installed.